# LINQ get a record with max date from multiple joins

Tags: c#, sql, .net, linq

I have three tables: Courses, CourseLocations, CourseSchedules

Each Course can be held in one or more Locations (1-to-many)
Each Location can host one or more Schedules (1-to-many)

I need to get all the courses, unique names, that have a Schedules.Date> Today and show also the MAX value of the date contained in the table CourseSchedules

My current linq code is:

```
var courses = (from c in db.Courses
           join cl in db.CourseLocations on c.CourseID equals cl.CourseID
           join cs in db.CourseSchedules on cl.CourseLocationID equals cs.CourseLocationID 

           where c.CourseStatusID == 1 && c.DeleteDate == null && ((c.CourseCategoryID == 1 && cs.EndDate >= courseEndDateFilter) || (c.CourseCategoryID == 3))

           select new
           {
               c.CourseID,
               CourseName = c.Name,
               CourseEndDate = cs.EndDate
           }).Distinct().OrderBy(o => o.CourseCategoryID).ThenBy(o => o.CourseName);
```

Where courseEndDateFilter is a variable used to define the date to filter.

The problem with the above query is that I get all the courses duplicated and not only the one with the MAX value of cs.EndDate

Is there a way (efficient) to do it?

Comment: you need to do `group by` here i think

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@Ehsan is correct. You need a group by and then get the max value of EndDate.  Given the following models:

```
    public class Course
    {
        public int CourseID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int CourseStatusID { get; set; }
        public int CourseCategoryID { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DeleteDate { get; set; }
    }

    public class CourseLocation
    {
        public int CourseLocationID { get; set; }
        public int CourseID { get; set; }
    }

    public class CourseSchedules
    {
        public int CourseLocationID { get; set; }
        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    }
```

I created the following in memory objects:

```
        var courses = new List<Course>
        {
            new Course { CourseID = 1, Name = "Test1", CourseCategoryID = 1, CourseStatusID = 1, DeleteDate = null },
            new Course { CourseID = 2, Name = "Test2", CourseCategoryID = 1, CourseStatusID = 1, DeleteDate = null },
            new Course { CourseID = 3, Name = "Test3", CourseCategoryID = 3, CourseStatusID = 1, DeleteDate = null }
        };
        var courseLocations = new List<CourseLocation>
        {
            new CourseLocation{ CourseID = 1, CourseLocationID = 1 },
            new CourseLocation{ CourseID = 2, CourseLocationID = 1 },
            new CourseLocation{ CourseID = 3, CourseLocationID = 1 },
            new CourseLocation{ CourseID = 1, CourseLocationID = 2 },
            new CourseLocation{ CourseID = 2, CourseLocationID = 2 },
            new CourseLocation{ CourseID = 3, CourseLocationID = 2 }

        };
        var courseSchedules = new List<CourseSchedules>
        {
            new CourseSchedules { CourseLocationID = 1, EndDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(10) },
            new CourseSchedules { CourseLocationID = 1, EndDate = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1) }
        };
```

Then the query would be the following to get Max EndDate:

```
var result = (from c in courses
                join cl in courseLocations on c.CourseID equals cl.CourseID
                join cs in courseSchedules on cl.CourseLocationID equals cs.CourseLocationID

                where c.CourseStatusID == 1 && c.DeleteDate == null &&
                      (c.CourseCategoryID == 1 && cs.EndDate >= DateTime.Now || c.CourseCategoryID == 3)

                select new
                {
                    c.CourseID,
                    CourseName = c.Name,
                    CourseEndDate = cs.EndDate,
                    c.CourseCategoryID
                })
            .GroupBy(arg => new
            {
                arg.CourseID,
                arg.CourseName,
                arg.CourseCategoryID
            })
            .Select(grouping => new
            {
                grouping.Key.CourseID,
                grouping.Key.CourseName,
                CourseEndDate = grouping.Max(arg => arg.CourseEndDate),
                grouping.Key.CourseCategoryID
            })
            .OrderBy(o => o.CourseCategoryID)
            .ThenBy(o => o.CourseName);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this will work since it's not like I can actually compile it.

The problem I see right away is that you're filter by a few things at the base, some of which don't include the locations but you want the date from the locations anyway...

```c#
var courses = (from c in db.Courses

       join cl in db.CourseLocations on c.CourseID equals cl.CourseID
       join cs in db.CourseSchedules on cl.CourseLocationID equals cs.CourseLocationID 

       where c.CourseStatusID == 1 && c.DeleteDate == null && (c.CourseCategoryID == 3 ||
       db.CourseLocations.Any(cl => cl.CourseID equals c.CourseID && 
           db.CourseSchedules.Any(cs => cs.CourseLocationID equals cl.CourseLocationID && 
               ((c.CourseCategoryID == 1 && cs.EndDate >= courseEndDateFilter))
           )
       ))

       select new
       {
           c.CourseID,
           CourseName = c.Name,
           CourseEndDate = db.CourseSchedules.Where(cs => db.CourseLocations.Any(cl => cl.CourseID equals c.CourseID && cs.CourseLocationID equals cl.CourseLocationID)).Max(cs => cs.EndDate),
           c.CourseCategoryID
       });
```